# DLL Instance error in several calls to a WebAPI

Tags: dll, com, release, webapi, using

i am trying to solve an error in a WebAPI that uses a COM Dll for a third party functions in a BMS software (Sage200)

The problem is that after many calls to the API, eventually it throws an Exception in the instance of the dll, in the InvokeMember.

I am using a IDisposable class with using () {}, and the Marshall.ReleaseCOMObject in the Dispose method, but the problem exists.

An example of my code:

```
    public class LcOEM: IDisposable
    {
        private object? lcOEM;
        private Type? typeObject;

        public LcOEM(short enterprise_code)
        {
            FinalizaOEM();

            typeObject = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM");
            lcOEM = Activator.CreateInstance(typeObject);

            string[] arguments = { enterprise_code.ToString(), Configuration.OEMUser, Configuration.OEMPass, "", Configuration.Server, Configuracion.DataBase };

            // method invocation
            var result = (string)typeObject.InvokeMember("InicializaOEM", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, lcOEM, arguments);
        }

        ~LcOEM()
        {
            FinalizaOEM();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            FinalizaOEM();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        public void FinalizaOEM()
        {
            if (lcOEM != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(lcOEM);
                lcOEM = null;
                typeObject = null;
            }
        }
```

An example of using de lcOEM class:

```
        using (LcOEM oem = new LcOEM(enterprise_code))
        {
          // GetNumer is a method of the dll. It is called using the InvokeMember of the object typeObject
            doc_number = oem.GetNumber("ALBARAN_CLI", Year, Serial);
        }
```

It works perfectly, but when a certain number of calls, it throws an exception when doing the Activator.CreateInstance call: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Am i doing the release com object right? Must i do something more to release the dll after exit the using clause?

Thenks,

Marcos.

It occur when the WebAPI is called several times. I want to release well the dll COM object because it is blocking the process.

The instruction in the Dispose method: GC.SuppressFinalize(this) is new, i have not tried with this but i don't think that it is the solution.

Comment: What is the full exception (and inner exceptions) you get? The code you show doesn't show everything; why do you store the object and type as members of the class? etc. Is the component ok to work in a web site (thread issues)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i'll modify the response to get the full exception but some explamples are:
-2146232828 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
or
-2147221001 Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {C2583D2F-B3D3-40B4-9C9B-7F60BD0358B4} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800401f7 Some error in application program (0x800401F7 (CO_E_ERRORINAPP))

I store the object and type as members of the class in order to instance the class in a using clause and not need load the dll in a subsecuent calls. When exits the using clause, dispose

Comment: I am doing it in a WebAPI application.

Comment: -2146232828/TargetInvocationException is useless. 0x800401F7/CO_E_ERRORINAPP is more interesting but quite unusual. Could be a threading issue. Impossible to tell more w/o more information, code, et. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to get a complete information about the exception.

Comment: You won't get more information about the exception (that is: we know what it is CO_E_ERRORINAPP, and this is not super useful). What's important is more information about what you're doing, reproducible code, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all. The error code and the answer that i have is given by the api invoked so it is difficult to obtain the inner text exception. I have solved this modifying the web application starting the instance to the dll at the start of the service, and closing in the stopping process. After that, i have no errors but i don't know the possible error. I believe that is an error in the COM object. Thanks for all.